# how to pause a script of python

Tags: python

I tried `time.sleep(secs)`. However this has to sleep for some specific seconds. It is not totally paused. Does Python have any function to pause the script forever if there is no any input ? Thanks !

Comment: define 'input': a signal, keystroke, network I/O, what?

Comment: @isedev does Python have any specific existing function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to pause until keyboard entry try:

```
raw_input("press enter")
```

Answer (score 2):

`sys.stdin.readline()` blocks until you enter input.